# Native American Society in a World Where Beringia Is Still High and Dry

Tags: society, alternate-history, culture

Multiple times in Earth's geological history, a bridge connected Asia to North America, bringing in an influx of colonists. Without Beringia, North America would never have the iconic *Triceratops* or *Tyrannosaurus*. Without Beringia, cats, dogs, bears, horses, rhinos, tapirs and even camels might never have colonized the entire northern hemisphere.

So let's say that, for whatever geological reason, Beringia stayed high and dry after the end of the last glaciation 13,000 years ago and has been a bridge connecting Asia to North America ever since. The focus is--how would the persisted existence of Beringia affect the course of history in regards to the peoples of North America?

Comment: With  a land bridge between the arctic and west coast of american continent...the ocean currents and climate will be different. This would greatly affect the people living in NAmerica.  Eg, if it's colder/warmer/wetter/dryer settlement patterns change etc. As you are looking at society and culture, I assume you have already worked out the climate dynamics. Can you provide a very brief outline?

Comment: I agree with @EveryBitHelps. Climate will be the most important issue here. I do not a direct impact on history and migration patterns: there was never a major kingdom anywhere near the Bering strait, and the natives can cross it easy enough on kayaks in summer, or over the ice in winter.

Comment: Is anyone thinking this question is a little broad?

Comment: @VogonPoet  How?

Comment: “how would the [anything] affect the course of history in regards to the peoples of North America” will be an encyclopedia and entirely opinions. Do you mean economics? Trade? Agriculture? Technological advancement? Medicine? Wars? The answer is anything you want it to be. You’re asking “what if X happened?” [Here is how to ask questions in this forum](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Google "Paleogeography".  There was no 'Berengia' for T-Rex.

Comment: @Joe  I didn't say that.  I said that if it weren't for Beringia, we Americans would never have had Tyrannosaurus.  Its ancestors were Asian.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - and I said - there was NO BERENGIA ( this is exactly why I avoid you) - look at a map of the world in those times and before...there wasn't even a 'North America'  The first paragraph in your vague question looks like it was copied elsewhere ( No Horses in North America )

Comment: @Joe  "There wasn't even a 'North America'".  So what would you have me say it, then?  Some random, unnamed continent?  Leaves nothing to the imagination, wouldn't you say?

Comment: You're asking about the effect of a major change over thousands of years, it's far too much for this format.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the biggest one with the exception of climate (which, admittedly, is a big exception) would be animals can still cross the Beringian land bridge. The Beringian land bridge tended to be relatively warm and ice free during much of its existence, covered by a cold steppe known as the "mammoth steppe" (which has been argued to have been maintained by the droppings of herbivorous megafauna, but still).

What this means is if the land bridge never floods there is now nothing to stop horses, camels, and saiga antelope from simply crossing back over the land bridge and recolonizing North America. All three groups are found in Mongolia to some degree, the same place where the ancestors of most Native American groups dispersed to North America from. Indeed, something similar happened to mountain lions, they are thought to have been mostly wiped out in North America at the end of the last ice age and [recolonized the continent from South America](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-12741-1). Which means the local cultures in North America might have access to camels and horses. And that kind of access to large, potentially domesticatable animals would have massive effects on history, the same way horses and camels did in Eurasia. Siberian tigers might also get into North America this way, and find North America ripe for the taking in a land where saber-toothed cats and American lions are extinct.

Comment: That does not answer the question.  Like, at all.